# Does fwrite() overwrite when called multiple times?

Tags: c, file, helper, fwrite

Example: I am going through a tree and fwriting based on preorder traversal.

This is pseudocode:

```
void func x (/* */, /* */)
{
  do something 
  helper (char * filename, thing to be written);
}

void helper (char * filename, thing to be written)
{
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"w");
  fwrite(/* */, /* */, /* */,fp);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Would it overwrite previous entries? If so, how can I prevent this?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you don't want it to overwrite then either only open the file once and use the same `fp` for every function call or `fopen` with `"a+"` for file append. See [fopen man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) for more details.

Comment: @kaylum thank you. So can I pass ```fp``` into the helper function as an argument ?

Comment: @fresh42juice — yes, pass the opened file pointer to `helper()`.  Do not close the file pointer in `helper()`.

Answer (score 0):

As kaylum mentioned, the short answer is yes it does.

fopen with "w" will open the file at the beginning, so any writes will truncate and overwrite. In order to avoid this, either reuse the file pointer returned by fopen every time, or use "a" in order to set fwrite to append mode.

Comment: I already asked this but - in that case would I be able to pass ```fp``` as an argument into the helper function ? Thank you.

Comment: since I am doing preorder traversal recursion will be involved, how would I avoid opening the file multiple times ? I am a little confused.

Comment: @fresh42juice: Before calling `inorder_traversal()`, open the file stream: `FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "a");`.  Call `inoder_traversal(root, fp);`.  When it returns, `fclose(fp);`.  Don't forget to check that the file was opened successfully.

Comment: I should have added: Inside `inorder_traversal()`, pass the file pointer to relevant functions that it invokes.  If necessary, modify the functions to take a file pointer instead of a file name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think I understand, thank you. So basically before I even start my tree traversal I open the file stream. And pass into my traversal function - this function in turn calls a helper which fwrites into the file. I would pass my ```fp``` into this helper as well. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @fresh42juice – yes, that's what I'm suggesting.  File opening is a slow process; do it as little as necessary.